# Loop through UIView and update UILabel values

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
func setNavigation(titleText: String, subtitleText: String) {
    // Need to update two labels inside of subtitleView

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.subtitleView
}
```

The `subtitleView` variable is of type `UIView`. The view contains only two labels, both of which I need to set to the function argument values. How can I loop through `subtitleView` to find these two labels and update their values?

This code I tried found the labels but failed to update the text values to "A":

```
func setNavigation(titleText: String, subtitleText: String) {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.subtitleView.subviews.count; i++) {
        if self.subtitleView.subviews[i].isKindOfClass(UILabel) {
            var labelReference: UILabel = self.subtitleView.subviews[i] as UILabel
            labelReference.text = "A"
        }
    }

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.subtitleView
}
```

Comment: You need to do some troubleshooting. Try logging self.subtitleView.subviews[i] in your for loop and see what it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom class that subclasses UIView and has variables for the 2 UILabels.

Or you can loop through all of the subviews for the UIView and set the label:

```
for view in self.subtitleView.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let labelReference = view as? UILabel{
         labelReference.text = "A"
         NSLog("Updating Label")
    }
}
```

If the text is not updating, check if you see the NSLog above print anything to the output. If not, I believe your UILabels may be nil.

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to do this without subclassing (only because it's fairly simple and I know there's a fixed amount of labels). I have tried the code you have put in your answer, the label values aren't set as "A" when this code is invoked, they're just blank :-(

Comment: Could you initialize your UIlabel's to have some text and then try it? Also, is this code done in a normal function or in an asynchronous block?

Comment: I tried initialising the labels with empty strings as you suggested but annoyingly this made no difference. The code is executed in a normal function.

Comment: No, do not initialize with empty strings, but with some default text to see if your labels show at all.

Comment: Could you also post where you create your UIView with your UIlabel? I have a feeling that your UILabels may be nil. Add an NSLog into where you set your text to "A" and see if it is ever called.